# Python3 Keylogger for MacOs : Script not working

Tags: python-3.x, macos, keylogger, pynput

I am trying to run a simple Keylogger using Python3 on MacOs. Below is the script.

```
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener



count = 0
keys = []

def on_press(Key):
    global keys, count
    print("hello")
    keys.append(Key)
    count += 1
    print(f"{Key} pressed")

    if count >= 10:
        count = 0
        write_file(keys)
        keys = []

# hello this is a test for the keylogger.

def write_file(keys):
    with open("logger.txt", "a") as f:
        for key in keys:
            f.write(str(key))



def on_release(Key):
    if Key == Key.esc:
        return False




with Listener(on_press= on_press, on_release = on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

The code displays which key is pressed on the console and also after every some period, it stores the keys pressed in a file. When I run the script using sudo, nothing is happening when I press some keys. I am not being shown which keys are pressed on the console and the file is also empty.

I am not able to understand what is the problem. I am guessing it's something related to MacOs restrictions for giving full access to the keyboard. But I am not sure.

Please someone help me on this.

Comment: Why do you want to run a keylogger with sudo?

Comment: Because when I normally do it using python3 filename.py, I am facing the same problem. So I thought maybe it's due to admin restrictions, let's try it with sudo. But no use.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53088995/pynput-keyboard-listener-does-not-detect-keys-on-mac-os-x) help?

Comment: yup tried it. it works. So, I need to add terminal and my IDE for this to work. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You're welcome. This Question was recommended as relative :)

Comment: yeah I just noticed this question on the related tab. Sorry for bothering you without noticing it. :)

Comment: No problem ;) I mean that's what SO tries to do: always have the answer. Can I add my comment as an answer?

Comment: yeah you are right.  sure, please do :)

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution in a related question. For security reasons MacOS does not allow keylogging by default. 
So you need to enable it manually:

> 1. Settings -> Security & Privacy
> 2. Click on the Privacy tab
> 3. Click the + and hold down CMD + SHIFT + . (so that you can see hidden files/folders)
> 4. Navigate to /usr/local/bin or wherever you have Python installed
> 5. Click okay.

cited from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54659886/12846952)