# "This process is not trusted" when running code in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Can't seem to find any solution to the problem. When I try to run the following code the console response with "*This process is not trusted! Input event monitoring will not be possible until it is added to accessibility clients.*"

I am using PyCham on a MacOS Big Sur device. My Mac is not asking for any permissions. I ran exact same code on a Windows machine without any problems. Can't find any help online.

What am I missing??

```py
import pyautogui
from pynput import keyboard


def on_activate_h():
    print(pyautogui.position())


with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({"<ctrl>+<alt>+r": on_activate_h}) as h:
    h.join()
```

Comment: I think the same problem is on Linux. All for security reason. It may need some changes in system. It may work if you run it with `sudo` (`SuperUserDO`) to have admin/root privilages - `sudo python script.py`. So all this is not problem with PyCharm or Python code but only with system settings which want to make your system secure.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why PyCharm isn't working correctly. I am using Visual Studio Code and I had the same problem as you.

#### A. Terminal.app (temporary solution)

If we run it in the `Terminal.app` and give that permissions, then it should work for you like it did for me.

1. Settings -> `Security & Privacy`
2. Click on the `Privacy` tab
3. Scroll and click on the `Accessibility` Row
4. Click the `+`
5. Navigate to `/System/Applications/Utilities/` or wherever the `Terminal.app` is installed
6. Click okay.

[Alternate solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54659886/3885246)

#### B. [py2app](https://pypi.org/project/py2app/) (distributable app)

Another approach is to use [py2app](https://pypi.org/project/py2app/) to make a `*.app` and give that permissions.

1. Make a setup.py

```py
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['main.py'] # points to your main python file
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {
    'packages': ['pynput'] # include your other dependencies here
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

2. In the terminal, run `pip install py2app`
3. And then, `python setup.py py2app`

   - This will make a folder named `dist`.
4. Add `./dist/main.app` to the Accessibility tab using the same steps as the first solution.
5. Just to be sure, add `main` (in the folder `./dist/main.app/Contents/MacOS/`) to the Accessibility tab. You can type the directory in the window by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>
6. Either open the app in Finder or run it in the console.

Answer (score 1):

You may look at Mac Setting - Privacy - Input Listener
then allow PyCharm.app to listen input from keyboard√

Comment: If using VSCode, `System Settings` -> `Privacy & Security` -> `Input Monitoring` -> allow `Visual Studio Code`

Answer (score 0):

I run on vs code terminal and below step for allow listen event:

1. Open System Setting > Privacy & Security
2. Open Input Monitoring
3. Press '+' button and add vscode-app to the list

[image]